# Resync AppCenter events to AppInsight

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I have a App Center config to sync to both Storage and App Insight below

[image]

Everything goes syncing smoothly until yesterday I have checked that it's been disabled 20 days syncing to App Insight (up to know I still don't know why it turned disabled by human or other), whereas Blob still going through. So then I enabled it and I see App Center continues export to App Insight at present but not these 20 days disabled before.

So now I have to get these backups from Blob (json files) to import to App Insight basically because App Center have no aibility to re-push it.

[image]

The question is what is the effective way to push these data to App Insight?

1. Collect all Blob of 20 days missing and push onto App Insight via REST API. But up to now I didn't find out what POST method for importing data, only GET for retrieving query
2. Also collect all Blob of 20 days missing, but using via App Insight SDK. That would be a little bit weird because it's responsible for pushing tracking-monitoring data at runtime, not a mission of push backward

Thank you for reading my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post api of application insights, the url is `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track`.

You can use any tools or program languages with post method to send request to this url, but you need to define the data properly.

Here is an example with c#:

```
        //the url
        string appinsights_url = "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track";
        Uri uri = new Uri(appinsights_url);

        //construct the telemetry data
        string data1 = "{\"name\":\"AppTraces\",\"time\":\"2020-12-21T02:11:51.9170725Z\",\"iKey\":\"your_key\",\"tags\":{\"ai.application.ver\":\"1.0.0.0\",\"ai.cloud.roleInstance\":\"ss-75821\",\"ai.internal.sdkVersion\":\"il:2.16.0-18277\",\"ai.internal.nodeName\":\"ss-75821.mmmmmmm.com\"},\"data\":{\"baseType\":\"MessageData\",\"baseData\":{\"ver\":2,\"message\":\"a message from post api: Information\",\"severityLevel\":\"Information\",\"properties\":{\"DeveloperMode\":\"true\",\"CategoryName\":\"WorkerService1.Worker\",\"OriginalFormat\":\"a message from post api: Information\"}}}}";                 

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var result = client.UploadString(appinsights_url, data1);
```

[image]

**The problem** here is that in the data body, the `time field` cannot be 48 hours earlier then the current time. There is no way to change this feature.

if you want to use [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics)(like using `TrackEvent`, `TrackTrace` methods) to send these data to application insights, it actually calls the above post method as well. But it's much easier to build the data body. And also, you can easily add some additional field to specify it's `original date`(since the `time field` cannot be 48 hours earlier then the current time).

Comment: Thank you Yang. After few days researched, I have decided to end it up by pushing these raw data to Data Warehouse directly, instead of going through App Insight as a part of current pipeline. The POST API would be helpful for who've just missed within 48 hours, otherwise specifying original date would be painful because the whole pipeline need to be refactored, whereas 20 days missing tracking are not so important to trade off. Anyway, your effort on tracing via fiddler are acknowledged & appreciated, thank you so much.